# How to interpret the sum of the elements of an inverse covariance matrix?

Tags: covariance, matrix-inverse

In the derivation of global minimum variance portfolio, we get The $(Σ^{-1}1) /(1'Σ^{-1}1)$. What's the meaning of $1'Σ^{-1}1$  and $Σ^{-1}1$. $Σ$ is a covariance matrix of assets returns.

Answer (score 2):

A good way is perhaps to recall that if $\varSigma$ is invertible with rank $p$, then it represents a strictly positive convex parabola in $p$ dimensional space. Therefore $\varSigma^{-1}$ is a valid weighting matrix (bounded and maximum at the global minimum of the parabola and vanishing quadratically as we move away from that point along any directions in $\mathbb{R}^p$). Then, $1'\varSigma^{-1}1$ is the sum of those weights (and  $\varSigma^{-1}1$ a $p$-vector giving for each entry the weights of that entry).